# Structs "puras" (sem ponteiro) e tratamento de erros em C

Tags: c, struct

Mexendo com estruturas de dados (`filas`, `pilhas`, etc), cheguei a um impasse ao tentar criar funções de busca para estas estruturas.

Por padrão, as funções que podem conter erros retornam 0 ou até -1 quando o tipo de retorno é um inteiro.

> Mas e se o tipo de retorno de uma função for uma struct e um erro foi encontrado?

Ao buscar um determinado tipo de dado em uma árvore, por exemplo, em uma função com o seguinte protótipo:

```
typedef struct registro {
    int valor;
    // outros dados...
} Registro;

// Supondo que o tipo Árvore já foi criado

Registro busca(Arvore a, int valor);
```

Caso o registro seja encontrado na árvore, beleza, retorna a struct que contém esse valor. Mas e se ela não for encontrada? Retorno o quê?

Comment: O mais recomendado mesmo é você pensar em ponteiros - a idéia de retornar as structs em si pode parecer mais simples - mas por dentro do programa acontecem coisas estranhas: ou você gerencia a alocação de memória para sua struct manualmente, ou, se ela for uma variável declarada dentro da sua função, os valores da função retornada nuam chamada anterior podem ser alterados por uma nova chamada à função.

Comment: Algumas destas respostas lhe atenderam?

Answer (score 2):

Se não podes mudar a função para devolver um ponteiro e devolver `NULL` em caso de erro, sugiro um elemento com valor especial

```
const struct registro especial_erro = {-1, ...};
struct registro busca(Arvore a, int valor) {
    /* ... */
    if (erro) return especial_erro;
}
```

Se podes mudar a função, usa `NULL` para indicar erro

```
struct registro *busca(Arvore a, int valor) {
    /* ... */
    if (erro) return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Boa sugestão essa primeira para o caso de gente exigente.

Answer (score 0):

Retone `NULL`.

Já que o retorno será do tipo Struct, retorne `NULL` e o faça uma verificação parecida com essa:

```
void foo(){
    if(retornaStruct() == NULL){ // Com erro, retornado NULL
        printf("ERRO!!!!\n\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Aí é que tá, se eu usasse ponteiro para struct seria fácil, pois eu faria o que tu falou mesmo, retornaria NULL na função.. O problema é se eu quisesse trabalhar com as structs sem ser com ponteiro, entende?

Answer (score 0):

Código de remoção de um Nó, nele é possível ver os tipos de retorno, veja que o retorno é um `noL` (no cabeçalho `noL *remove_no_lista`) e que há um `return NULL` ao final da função posterior a vários `return` de `structs` de tipo `noL` (tipo de retorno especificado).

```
typedef struct No
    {
        char info;
        int numeracao; // facilita a busca em caso de duplicacao
        struct No *esq,*dir;
    }no;
typedef struct NoL
    {
        no *noA;
        struct NoL *prox;
    }noL;

noL *remove_no_lista(noL *raiz,noL *noLista)
    {
        if(noLista != NULL)
            {
               noL *p = NULL;
               if(noLista == raiz)//caso seja raiz
                    {
                        p = raiz;
                        raiz = raiz->prox;
                        free(p);
                        return raiz;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        if(noLista->prox == NULL) //caso tenha 2 ou mais na lista
                            {
                                for(p = raiz; p->prox->prox != NULL; p = p->prox);
                                p->prox = NULL;
                                free(noLista);
                                return raiz;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                        for(p = raiz; p->prox != noLista; p = p->prox);//meio da lista
                                        p->prox = noLista->prox;
                                        free(noLista);
                                        return raiz;
                            }
                    }
            }
        else
            return NULL;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deveutilizar ponteiros para retornar buscas na estrutura de dados dinâmica. Até mesmo porque ela é feita e montada inteiramente com auxílio deles. Faça

```
void *busca(Arvore a, int valor); /* o poder do casting do void em C: 
                                     utilize ele! */
```

E retorne `NULL` caso não encontre o valor. Retorne um ponteiro para estrutura desejada caso encontre tal valor em sua árvore.